# Sending mail using javamail api from IBM Websphere Application Server 8

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-mail, websphere-8

How to send mail using gmail from IBM Websphere Application Server 8 using javamail 1.5.2 api because that give me a same error :

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, O=Equifax, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import Google certificate into the WebSphere's trust store.

WebSphere does not trust the certificate. You are trying to send an email to a server that uses SSL.

The easiest way is to use **Retrieve from port**

You can find info here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/ae/usec_sslretrievesignercert.html

Have you used correct values for retrieving?

- Host:    smtp.gmail.com
- Port:     465
- Alias: gmail

Comment: ok thanks @NikolaB for your answer but I have already done this before I ask question but I have the same error. So ?

Comment: @mariame Either you put it in the wrong store (it must be as singers in the trust store) or you didn't import whole certificate path. If it is signed by other singers, you will have to import these signers also.